# XSS: How can I remove JS snippets from a String in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, xss

My usecase is actually quite simple.
Let's say I get an input argument like `abcdalert(document.cookie);` and I want to scrub it off the `(document.cookie);` part.
What is the most efficient way to do this in ASP.NET C#?

> PS: The snippet can be any JS code. Not necessarily alerts.

Comment: you should provide more examples of what kind of code d you want to keep and what to dispose..

Comment: maybe take a look at Antixss

Comment: @DorLugasi-Gal Mostly XSS based snippets that somebody might enter. Concentrating on JS based  attacks.

Comment: so why do you accept this and not introduce some kind of an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the `HtmlSanitizer` .Net library to apply server side sanitization

https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

This library used for cleaning HTML fragments and documents from potential XSS attacks. It uses AngleSharp to parse, manipulate, and render HTML and CSS. It is based on a robust HTML parser that can protect your code from deliberate or accidental "tag poisoning" where invalid HTML in one fragment can corrupt the whole document (which can lead to a broken layout or style)

Comment: This helped. Also, I used `HttpUtility` encoders to have a similar effect.